# I can't get response from php after running ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery and PHP to record comments. The jQuery part works fine, but I can't get PHP ready to record comments. jQuery returns alert 200 after sending, but I think I can't access to 'class' in PHP.

PHP:

```
class comments extends config{
    public function Action2($id,$comment){
        //record comment
    }
}

$input=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$new_comment=new comments();
$new_comment->Action2($input->id,$input->comment);
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'./comment.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    cache:false,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    data:JSON.stringify({
        'comment':comment,
        'id':id
    }),
});
```

Comment: you didn't put any echo etc. in your function to return to AJAX

Comment: i cant see the definition of class 'config', so it will give an an error 'Class 'config' not found'. You should either define it or link to the comment.php file. Otherwise the code will work fine after defining some action in Action2 method

Comment: What do you mean by "access to class"?

Comment: xottabych007: config has defined above the class

Comment: first of all you need to check not the code type, but the actual response tab of the ajax. Second you need your method Action2 to return a json, as you specified in the dataType: field of the ajax query. And finaly you might want to handle the response of the server by adding the "success: function(result) {
  console.log(result);
 }" to your ajax query